# Proving Fermat's Little Theorem by Induction

Tags: prime-numbers, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic

A common form of Fermat's Little Theorem is: $a^{p}=a$ (mod $p$), for any prime $p$ and integer $a$. Prove this by induction on $a$.

I tried to prove that $(a+b)^p= a^p+b^p$ (modulo $p$) since it's a more general statement, but couldn't get further.

Comment: You are on the right track.  Why haven't you tried evaluating $(a+b)^p$ using binomial expansion?  Isn't this the obvious thing to try when confronted with an expression like $(a+b)^p$?

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I will try now.

Answer (score 4):

$(a+1)^P=a^p+ \binom{p}{1} a^{p-1} +\binom{p}{2}a^{p-2}+.....+ \binom{p}{p-1}a+1.$

Note that $p$ divides into any binomial coefficient of the form $\binom{p}{k}$
 for $1 \le k\le p-1$

This follows by the definition of the binomial coefficient as $\binom{p}{k}= \left(\frac{p!}{k!(p-k)!}\right)$; since $p$ is prime, then $p$ divides the numerator but not denominator.

Taken mod $p$, all of the middle terms disappear, and we end up with

$(a+1)^p\equiv a^p +1$ (mod $p$). Since we also know that $a^p\equiv a$ (mod $p$)

$(a+1)^p\equiv a +1$ (mod $p$). As we needed

Comment: the right hand should be a fraction but I keep formatting it a bit wrong still learning the language. forgive me. Nvm fixed!